# \jobname of included file does not work in references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

Here is a SmallWorkingExample.

**Main File: 1.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\newcounter{exp}%[ 
\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= exp,%
number within=chapter,%
Crefname={Example}{Examples},%
]%
{example}%
[2][]%
{%
title={EXAMPLE  \thetcbcounter .\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm} #2}{}}, #1%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{\jobname-0}
\section{First of ONE}\label{\jobname-1}
\begin{example}[label={exp:\jobname-1}]{~}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{example}
See \Cref{exp:1-1} on \cpageref{exp:1-1} in \Cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1}  in \Cref{1-0} \nameref{1-0}

See \Cref{exp:2-1} on \cpageref{exp:2-1} in \Cref{2-1}  \nameref{2-1} in \Cref{2-0} \nameref{2-0}
\include{2}
\end{document}
```

**Included file: 2.tex**

```
\chapter{TWO}\label{\jobname-0}
\section{First of TWO}\label{\jobname-1}
\begin{example}[label={exp:\jobname-1}]{~}
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{example}
See \Cref{exp:1-1} on \cpageref{exp:1-1} in \Cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1}  in \Cref{1-0} \nameref{1-0}

See \Cref{exp:2-1} on \cpageref{exp:2-1} in \Cref{2-1}  \nameref{2-1} in \Cref{2-0} \nameref{2-0}
```

The references to Chapter ONE work, the references to the *included* ChapterTWO do not work even though LaTeX writes a **2.aux** file.

Would make my life a bit easier if it did.

Comment: the `\jobname` is still the master document `1`, not the included one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\jobname` is still `1` if `\include{2}` is applied, i.e. `\jobname` is not changed later on.

The `\include` command can be changed at little bit to store the current file in `\currentjobname`, using the first argument.

At the beginning of the document, `\currentjobname` defaults to `\jobname` and it should be `\jobname` again after `\include{...}` is finished, so use `\def` which is group-safe.

In my opinion it is no good idea to change `\jobname` itself.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%

\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
\def\currentjobname{\jobname}% 
\xpretocmd{\include}{\def\currentjobname{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{exp}%[ 

\usepackage{cleveref}%

\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= exp,%
number within=chapter,%
Crefname={Example}{Examples},%
]%
{example}%
[2][]%
{%
title={EXAMPLE  \thetcbcounter .\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm} #2}{}}, #1%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{\currentjobname-0}
\section{First of ONE}\label{\currentjobname-1}
\begin{example}[label={exp:\currentjobname-1}]{~}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{example}
See \Cref{exp:1-1} on \cpageref{exp:1-1} in \Cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1}  in \Cref{1-0} \nameref{1-0}

See \Cref{exp:2-1} on \cpageref{exp:2-1} in \Cref{2-1}  \nameref{2-1} in \Cref{2-0} \nameref{2-0}
\include{2}

\end{document}
```

The `2.tex` and `3.tex` file are effectively identical, I used them to show that the correct labels are written:

`2.tex`

```
\chapter{TWO}\label{\currentjobname-0}
\section{First of TWO}\label{\currentjobname-1}
\begin{example}[label={exp:\currentjobname-1}]{~}
yyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{example}
See \Cref{exp:1-1} on \cpageref{exp:1-1} in \Cref{1-1} \nameref{1-1}  in \Cref{1-0} \nameref{1-0}

See \Cref{exp:2-1} on \cpageref{exp:2-1} in \Cref{2-1}  \nameref{2-1} in \Cref{2-0} \nameref{2-0}
```

Comment: "Just what the doctor ordered". But I want to make absolutely sure with the Magnum Opus. Probably tonight.

Comment: @schremmer: I don't know what the Magnum Opus contains ... difficult to provide more

Comment: I don't know either but I have a feeling it will work.

Comment: Didn't work in the Magnum Opus.  If you are interested in pursuing, I cut a couple of chapters to make a small example which you can find at (http://freemathtexts.org/BU/RAFv7SmallWorking.zip) Typeset `Text-contents>1.tex` or `Text-controls>1.tex` (references work) and compare with typesetting `Text-contents>ALL.tex` or `Text-controls>ALL.tex`  (Not all references work). The file structure is more complicated because it does much better than what `\includeonly` does. You can also find my email address on the site.

Comment: @schremmer: Thanks for feedback. I'll try to look later on.

Comment: @schremmer: I can't typeset the `1.tex` file. There's no `\documentclass` and I don't like this `pdflatexmk` stuff, actually. The total stuff is disrupted

Comment: Back from titlesec! **1.** I removed the latexmark calls. I thought all latexmark did is to compile the right number of times.  **2.** In `Text-contents`, the first line of `X.tex`, where `X` stands for `n` or `ALL`,  is `%!TEX root = ../Text-controls/\jobname.tex` which should call `X.tex` in `Text-controls` whose first line is `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`. But you can typeset `X.tex` in `Text-controls` directly. **3.** This structure allows  typesetting Text-contents file(s) individually and at the same time the corresponding whole book by uncommenting them in `ALL.tex` in `Text-contents`